# Wordpress multiple URLs for RSS Feed: how to separate them?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I need to display 2 different feeds rss with Wordpress. I'm using this code:

```
$feed = fetch_feed(array('http://somewhere.rss', 'http://anotherplace.rss'));

// Loop the results
foreach($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    echo $item->get_title();
}
```

it works fine but the problem is how to separate the sources. It returns a big list with 2 sources data joined. How can I know what are the data from the first url and the second? The API on Wordpress' website is not clear about that.

Any idea?

Thanks

Randomize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wordpress Codex documentation, the `fetch_feed` function uses SimplePie.  When you iterate over the items, each item is an instance of SimplePie_Item.  So you should be able to use the `get_feed` method, such as:

```
$feed = fetch_feed(array('http://somewhere.rss', 'http://anotherplace.rss'));

// Loop the results
foreach($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    echo $item->get_title() . ' posted to ' . $item->get_feed()->get_title();
}
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thank for your reply, I've totally missed one reference link in the documentation. Anyway this is another good example: http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_source